# tfs2013 - exportprocessconfig produces invalid xml

Tags: tfs, scrumboard

TFS2013
Edit: Additional info as per comment:
I'm trying to add a "blocked" swim lane to my task board.
So as per instructions I run:

```
witadmin.exe exportprocessconfig /collection:http://{my collection} /p:{my project} /f:config.xml
```

It generates the XML as expected 
If I immediately run (without editing the xml):

```
witadmin.exe importprocessconfig /collection:http://{my collection} /p:{my project} /f:config.xml /v
```

I get:

```
Line: 3 Position: 4 - The required attribute `pluralName` is missing.
```

So basically the XML generated by witadmin exportprocessconfig is invalid?!

Comment: You should probably give more informations about what you are trying to achieve as well as the specific error you got (Copy / Paste your logs for example?)

Comment: Edited my question to give more info...

Comment: @SamClayton, can you please post atleast the first 3-4 lines of your XML?

Answer (score 4):

exportprocessconfig creates a BROKEN xml file (according to importprocessconfig /v)
I amended line 3 from:

```
     <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" singularName="Bug">
```

To:

```
     <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" singularName="Bug" pluralName="Bugs">
```

then carried out my own changes and it worked.
Kinda sucks that the export is not compatible with the import on the same tool.

Comment: Thanks Sam - not exactly rocket science but useful to know that someone saw this before I did.